# More than one start menu item with electron-builder

Tags: electron, electron-builder

Is it possible, with electron-builder, to have more than one entry in the start menu, to call the application with different set of arguments? How?

Comment: I don't think this is possible(To my knowledge) But you could do the same thing by using electron as a container and have multiple apps loading dynamically. its not a disk space saver but you can replicate the app and pass different set of arguments. A silly workaround really. can provide more detail if interested

Comment: You could add a [custom NSIS script](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/NSIS#custom-nsis-script) and use [CreateShortCut](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/CreateShortCut). Windows only though.

Comment: @UlugToprak: electron-builder, as far as I know, can only distribute one app, so, your proposal only shifts the problem to something else that is impossible.

Comment: @Pablo Its actually possible, `default_app` supports loading other apps dynamically. investigate the `main.js` further if you like, see how the option.file is handled. Aim is to list multiple apps through your default asar and when one of the listed apps are chosen it will load like the default does `(require('module')._load(packagePath, module, true);)` You can also create a shell script for each app and pass the path of the app you want to load to your branded electron

Comment: @UlugToprak what is the default_app? I cannot find it in electron-builder's docs.

Comment: @Pablo please refer to electrons [repository](https://github.com/electron/electron/tree/master/default_app) for file structure. default_app is the default page displayed if you have no apps provided when electron starts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this creating a [custom NSIS script](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/wiki/NSIS#custom-nsis-script) called build/installer.nsh calling [CreateShortCut](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Reference/CreateShortCut) like this:

```
!macro customInstall
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\App 2.lnk" "$INSTDIR\app.exe" "--mode=2"
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\App 3.lnk" "$INSTDIR\app.exe" "--mode=3"
!macroend
```